# What is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra of reals that is closed under addition of sets?

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

What is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ containing the open sets and such that if $A,B\in\Sigma$, then $$A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}\in\Sigma?$$

I know that neither the Borel $\sigma$-algebra nor the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra work, but it is already unclear to me what happens with $\sigma(\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1(\Bbb R))$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the analytic sets (of course the sum of two analytic sets is analytic, but I'm not sure what happens already with $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$ sets).

I'm interested in this question for arbitrary perfect Polish groups, but let's start with the (hopefully) easiest case.

Comment: I take it the trivial upper bound is $\mathbf{\Delta}^2_1$?

Comment: If you start with the open sets, then generate using sigma-algebra operations and sums, do you get at least all the analytic sets?

Comment: I might be going off of a wild guess, but I suspect an argument like the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2785650/127263) might be able to get that in appropriate sense such sets are closed under projections. This way perhaps one can show this class is equal to the class of $\sigma$-projective sets.

Comment: That seems like a very good guess @Wojowu, let's see if I can work out the details